# I'm using a raspberry pi 3 with raspian stretch lite. Where are the files I create saved?

Tags: image, raspberry-pi, directory, storage, raspberry-pi3

I'm doing a project with my pi 3 without the gui partially because I want to challenge myself and partially so that my eventual report will look better.

Anyway, I was wondering where/how exactly the directories I interact with are stored. My project involves taking pictures with the camera module. I thought that they were going to be saved on the microSD card with the bootloader, but now that I write that, it sounds kind of naive.

I've decided to just stick a USB into the device and use that to transfer the files, which has its own problems, but that's not what I'm asking.

When I used a microSD>SD>USB adapter set-up to look for the images I had created when starting out, all I could find was what looked like a partition dedicated to holding all of the scripts the pi uses when booting. Were my pictures being saved to some internal memory on the pi itself? I've been trying to find out if the pi even has internal memory, but have so far been stymied. Even if I looked  up the data sheet and found that it did have maybe 8GB of long term storage, I would only be guessing and I was wondering if anyone with more experience with pis or other microcontrollers might know.

---

Comment: Your files are being saved on the sd card. The filesystem on the sd card is not going to be accessible on your Windows system. You would typically copy the files from the pi over the network, or configure things to save them onto a USB flash drive or something with a filesystem such as FAT that will work under both windows and linux. You may want to ask over on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going with the USB flash drive for convenience; I was just wondering and now feel elucidated. *thumbs up *